# Выполнить команду, если ошибка - выполнить вторую команду Python

Tags: python

подскажите как лучше реализовать подобную схему? Я сделал это через try-except-finally, но не уверен корректно ли так поступать?

```
def playsound(path):
    sound = ""
    try:
# первый вариант сработает если я укажу в функции полный путь какого-то файла
        sound = pyglet.media.load(path) 
# если же я укажу просто название файла, оно не сможет воспроизвести из-за 
# отсутствия пути и пойдет выполнять вторую команду
    except:
# вторая команда
        sound = pyglet.media.load("D:/Download/SoundPack/" + path)
    finally:
# третья команда, которая просто воспроизводит, ей всё равно какой вариант сработает.
        sound.play()
        pyglet.app.run()
```

Так вот, есть ли альтернативные, более правильные варианты реализации такой штуки? И такой код имеет место быть?
В коде всё время прописывать путь к mp3 файлу - не красиво выглядит, поэтому в функции указываю путь, где практически все лежат mp3 файлы, но есть случаи когда файл совсем в другой директории и я тогда в коде указываю путь.
Можно создать вторую функцию, можно переместить файл самостоятельно в нужную папку. Но я хочу именно в этой функции определять всю движуху.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

плохо тут только то, что except не определяет конкретный набор ожидаемых исключений. если в блоке try вы допустите синтаксическую ошибку, то это застравит код всегда выполняться через блок except. и вы даже не узнаете о проблеме. а я уверен, что исключение SyntaxError не является ожидаемым.

и переменную sound заранее объявлять не нужно. тем более с другим типом

Есть 2 правильных подхода с решению вашей проблемы. Первый - делай без спроса, а случае проблемы обработай ее

```
def playsound(path):
    try:
# первый вариант сработает если я укажу в функции полный путь какого-то файла
        sound = pyglet.media.load(path) 
# если же я укажу просто название файла, оно не сможет воспроизвести из-за 
# отсутствия пути и пойдет выполнять вторую команду
    except IOError:
# вторая команда
        sound = pyglet.media.load("D:/Download/SoundPack/" + path)
    finally:
# третья команда, которая просто воспроизводит, ей всё равно какой вариант сработает.
        sound.play()  # noqa чтобы скрыть ошибку от PyCharm
        pyglet.app.run()
```

Второй - лучше сначала спросить потом делать.

```
import os.path

def playsound(path):
    path = path if os.path.exists(path) else "D:/Download/SoundPack/" 
+ path
    sound = pyglet.media.load(path) 
    sound.play()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Но добавить обработку исключений, скорее всего, все равно придется. Вруг файл не является mp3. Поэтому я бы предпочел первый вариант.

Comment: В except я прописал  FileNotFoundError, именно такую ошибку мне выбивало бы если б файл был не найден. Так что мне в except оставить лучше, Ваше или моё исключение? + на счет переменной, мне после finally: sound.play() pycharm ругается мол нужно объявить переменную заранее.

Comment: FileNotFoundError это подкласс IOError, оставляйте IOError если хотите ловить любые ошибки ввода вывода. Чтобы IDE не ругалась добавьте `# noqa` в конец строки где редактор подсвечивает ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо за решение моей проблемы! Тема закрыта!